# object return random number instead of a value in perl

Tags: perl

I have this PM class file:

```
use strict ;
use warnings;

package Math;


sub new{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless($self, $class);
    return $self;
}


sub add{
    my $x = shift;
    my $y = shift;
    return $x + $y;
}

sub substract{

    my $x = shift;
    my $y = shift;
    return $x - $y;

}

sub multiple{

    my $x = shift;
    my $y = shift;
    return $x * $y;
}

sub divide{
    my $x = shift;
    my $y = shift;
    return $x / $y;
}

1;
```

and I have the main test pl file:

```
use strict ;
use warnings;
use Math;

my $math_action = new Math();
my $number1 = 5;
my $number2 = 3;
my $results = $math_action->add($number1, $number2);
print $results;
```

From some reason I am getting odd results randomly with each run.
Probably something easy (?) I did not touch perl for long time, digging an hour to find solution could not find ...Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The first argument is `$self`.

Comment: write me the code, I tried to pass 3 arguments but the same random results appear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use OOP in perl the first argument to each method is the thing you blessed

```
sub new{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};              <--  this hashref
    bless($self, $class);
    return $self;
}


sub add{
    my $self = shift;           <-- is the first argument in methods
    my $x = shift;
    my $y = shift;
    return $x + $y;
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks its working now, is there a way for me to remove $self and only stick to the variables that I actually need and used, it seems bit strange to declare the $self in each sub...

Comment: @user3906716 in perl $self is meant to store the programs state. this way every method can access the internal state of the object and retrieve or store object variables. Because of this it is not possible to get rid of $self if you want to program with the OOP paradigm in Perl.

Comment: @user3906716 You can call your functions like `Math::add($number1, $number2)` but then  you don't use the object, you call a method in the Math namespace. That's like calling a static method in c++/java

Comment: Thank you again Murphy, I made the change now I will have sample to work with in the future. I used perl a lot 3 years ago but mostly using sub without creating classes, now I am finally return to it. I was digging an hour for this. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @user3906716 glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is no more possible at Perl6, to access to object-methods as class-methods in a way of procedural subroutine calls. But now you can call the methods just without reference throw an instance resp. object and every think it's fine:

Like: **print add(2, 3)**. In your case, when your forget the declartaion and definition of the *blessed* reference-variable.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict ;
use warnings;
use Math;

my $math_action = new Math();
my $number1 = 5;
my $number2 = 3;
my $results = Math::add($number1, $number2);
print $results;
```

Comment: @user3906716 here people usually +1 answers / questions if they find them useful

Comment: May I suggest adding a little explanation as to why this works and what the OP did wrong?

Comment: @Benjamin W. it already has been mentioned above, the OP have sent 3 args to a function, while intended to send 2

Comment: I just think it would make your answer better as an independent entity if you mentioned that.